# Mapbox (ReactMapGL) map not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am a beginner in coding, and I can't seem to display the map in my react website

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but the map is not previewing [without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmiN.png)

If I insert a text inside the  block, it becomes like this: [with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk2aC.png)

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export default function App() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 45.4211,
    longitude: -75.6903,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 10
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken='pk.eyJ1IjoiYWNlZG9taW5nbyIsImEiOiJjbGpvOTB3ZjMwMWFiM2dxbDc5cjU0Y2FvIn0.aJC6z1-KjLBiG15MUfzO4Q'
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setViewport(viewport);
        }}
      >
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
}
```